# Can't get JSON using CURL (php)

Tags: php, json, curl

I thought I'm getting quite well with PHP/curl, but here I don't know what's all about?

[GET] https://www.olx.pl can be fetched with no problems, but I can't get JSON requesting:
[GET] https://www.olx.pl/i2/ajax/ad/getcontact/?id=477486803&type=phone

In browser it's fine, in POSTMAN it's fine (all security options off).

The code I execute:

```
$urlForTel = "https://www.olx.pl/i2/ajax/ad/getcontact/?id=477486803&type=phone";
$headers = array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0'
);
$ch = curl_init();
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlForTel);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

The code just stops and doesn't go forward... As you see I tried many different options (certs, proxy, with headers and without). However when you change e.g. last digit in ID in param (requesting non existing asset), it returns HTML correctly...

I tried 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);` with cert downloaded and with/without useragent as well...

Comment: Add [`curl_error($ch)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to see if the request returns any errors.

Comment: The behavoir remains the same... Nothing happens on stdout. I added `echo curl_error($ch)` after `curl_exec`.

Comment: Got anything in your php error log?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing... Does it work using CURL with your php configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with the given code, and managed to make it work by simply adding an `Accept` header like this:

```php
$headers = array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
    'Accept: application/json',
);
```